# Passing Variables values between different MOJO's

Tags: mojo

I have created two Maven Plugin MOJO's. 
Mojo 1 identifies the projects to be built. 
Mojo 2: The other MOJO tries to package and build each of the project identified by the previous MOJO.

I am trying to understand how can I pass projectnames identified by MOJO 1 to be used with MOJO2.

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sarat